# Open graph image on Facebook Sharing Debugger states image has an invalid content type

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I'm trying post on FB and on the in the sharing debugger, all of the og meta tags are being read properly except the og:image.

[Sharing debugger for my site](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgoldcoastcookiecompany.com%2F)

I've tried og:image:secure_url, and I've also added { og:"image:type", content: "image/png" }. In chrome devtools, the tags are populated:

[image: Devtools Screenshot]

I am at a loss, I've tried other debuggers and they show the same thing. What am I doing wrong for this image? What exact content type are they looking for? On the main page it is taking another image, when I go to /about the correct image is being read but there is still the invalid image content type.

One other thing to note. The message with the invalid content type refers to my source code path, the image that is rendered (in /about for example) seems to be from compiled code.